# How to load MongoDB data source to ActivePivot cube?

Tags: mongodb, activepivot

How to load MongoDB data source to ActivePivot cube? Is there any library available for that purpose? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can follow those steps:

- write a connector to Mongo based on a java driver (https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java/, http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.2/driver/getting-started/quick-tour/).
- then I'll use Jackson to convert the entries received from Mongo from JSON to Java objects (http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/).
- All the code above will sit in a source (let's call it Mongo Source), this source will implement Quartet co.qfs.msg.ISource so then when you call fetch while loading your data, you'll get all the entries you're looking for.